# Convert IEnumerable to System.Data.Linq.Table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a function whose return type is **Table**

This code does not work. I just want to return the IEnumerable as Linq.Table **

```
 public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Products> GetProducts()
    {
        MyContext mc = new MyContext();

        Table<Products> ret = null;
        // Or   Table<Products> ret = mc.GetTable<Products>();

        ret.AttachAll<Products>(mc.GetTable<Products>()
                                  .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Take(1));

        return ret;
    }
```

Now I want to cast IEnumerable query to System.Data.Linq.Table.

(You may say that I can change the return type but the question is whether this is possible. Can I override some function like GetTable()? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The [`Table<TEntity>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) exists in order to provide an [`IQueryable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) implementation.  There aren't any *actual* items in there, it's just a root that's exposed by the [`DataContext` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) in order to provide an `IQueryable<T>` implementation which is interpreted, translated to SQL and then sent to SQL server.

If you have an [`IEnumerable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) implementation, chances are you *already have* the materialized result set (or an in-memory collection) that you are iterating over.  There's no benefit to having an `IQueryable<T>` implementation because there's nothing to interpret; everything you want is already in memory.

That said, it's probably better to just use the regular extension methods/query syntax off your `IEnumerable<T>` implementation than trying to put it in a `Table<TEntity>`.